# Issue on updating Limits.conf on Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to install an application on top of `Ubuntu Server LTS 18.04` but I am getting this error:

[image]

so I called:

```
$ gedit admin:///etc/security/limits.conf
```

and the `limits.conf` opens. Then I added some lines to the end of file as seen below:

[image: ![enter image description here]

But after saving and then running:

```
$ ulimit -Hn -Hu
$ ulimit -Sn -Su
```

I'm still getting the same amount as they were:

[image]

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, but remove the tabs/spaces from the front of the lines

Comment: Also try testing the limits by manually setting them with the ulimit command itself. The limits.conf file will only take effect when you log in with a new session

Comment: Thanks Raman but which `tabs/spaces` you are talking about? and can you please let me know how I can manually set the limits

Comment: Move you siteadmin lines to the very beginning of the lines like the lines above that are commented out. Then log out and log back in. Check you limits on logging back in.

Comment: Thanks this change some thing here! but it just changed the Max User Process number to 25059 but the Open Files still showing the old number

Comment: Try setting it with ulimit -n so "ulimit -n 65535"

Comment: Should I have to add it inside the `limits.conf`? or through terminal?

Comment: Run the command in the terminal first

Comment: on terminal I am getting `ulimit-n: command not found`

Comment: Ok after `ulimit -n 35535` I am getting this ` Bash: ulimit: open files: can not modify limit:operation not permited`

Answer (score 2):

Put a file here (`/etc/security/limits.d`) instead of editing the actual `/etc/security/limits.conf` file.

```
$ cat /etc/security/limits.d/90-arcgis.conf
siteadmin       -       nofile    65536
siteadmin       -       nproc     25059
```

#### Example

Here I've setup a user `siteadmin` and logged into it. Here's this user's default limits:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 3875
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 3875
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

The user's `nproc` and `nofile` defaults are these:

```
max user processes              (-u) 3875
open files                      (-n) 1024
```

**NOTE:** These values restrict the user to these caps across all the processes they may invoke. Limits govern by user, so if you had 10 processes running, they're limited to 1024 files open period, for example.

Now if we add our file to `/etc/security/limits.d/90-arcgis.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/security/limits.d/90-arcgis.conf
siteadmin       -       nofile    65536
siteadmin       -       nproc     25059
```

And if we log into `siteadmin`:

```
$ su - siteadmin
Last login: Fri Jul 20 14:07:10 EDT 2018 on pts/0

$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 3875
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65536
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 25059
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Now we see our limits being picked up.

#### What's the deal with the `-`

In the limits.conf file you can specify `soft`, `hard` or both. The `-` means both.

Per the `man limits.conf` man page:

```
   <type>

       hard
           for enforcing hard resource limits. These limits are set by the 
           superuser and enforced by the Kernel. The user cannot raise his 
           requirement of system resources above such values.

       soft
           for enforcing soft resource limits. These limits are ones that 
           the user can move up or down within the permitted range by any 
           pre-existing hard limits. The values specified with this token 
           can be thought of as default values, for normal system usage.

       -
           for enforcing both soft and hard resource limits together.

           Note, if you specify a type of '-' but neglect to supply the item 
           and value fields then the module will never enforce any limits on 
           the specified user/group etc. .
```

#### References

- [How to set or change the default soft or hard limit for the number of user's processes?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/406663)